# install(TARGETS ...) and add_subdirectory

Tags: installation, cmake

Is it possible to use install(TARGETS ...) with targets that are defined in directories added with add_subdirectory?

My use case is, that I want to build e.gg an rpm for gtest. the gtest project happens to have a CMakeLists.txt without any install statements. I want to build the package without adding those statements to the CMakeLists.txt of gtest.

I have this resulting directory structure:

```
+ gtest-1.5.0/...
+ CMakeLists.txt
```

The CMakeLists of gtest-1.5.0 defines libraries like this:

```
cxx_static_library(gtest "${cxx_strict}" src/gtest-all.cc)
cxx_static_library(gtest_main "${cxx_strict}" src/gtest_main.cc)
target_link_libraries(gtest_main gtest)
```

now i want to add something like this to my CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_subdirectory(gtest-1.5.0)
install(TARGETS gtest gtest_main ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib)
```

but cmake correctly states:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:10 (install):
  install TARGETS given target "gtest" which does not exist in this
  directory.
```

Is there a way to do this without patching gtest-1.5.0?

Comment: It seems this limitation has been lifted, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/34444949/227322

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try using file install rather than install targets. The downside is that you will have to handle shared and static builds.

`install(FILES gtest-1.5.0/gtest_main.so DESTINATION lib)`

Comment: ok .. this could work, but i don't understand, why i can use the defined names in target_link_libraries and not in install commands!

Comment: the Install command only looks at the current directory when figuring out if a target exists, unlike target_link_libraries which scans all targets.

Comment: Ok ... thanks for the explanation, I thought something like this, but I was not sure (could you edit your install(FILES command, because install(FILES does not take the ARCHIVE parameter).