# CMake install (TARGETS in subdirectories)

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

Consider the following `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
add_subdirectory(execA)
add_subdirectory(libB)

install(TARGETS execA libB
        RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
        LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib)
```

I get the following error:

```
install TARGETS given target "execA" which does not exist in this
  directory
```

`execA` and `libB` have their own `CMakeList.txt` files and are located under `project` directory, as well as the build directory I'm running `cmake` (`cmake ..`):

```
project
  |------ CMakeList.txt (the one with the code)
  |----execA
  |      \- .cpp, .hpp and CMakelist.txt
  |----libB
  |      \- .cpp, .hpp and CMakelist.txt
  |---- lib
  |---- bin
  \---- build (where I´m commanding: $ cmake ..
```

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to [this bugreport](https://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=14444), `install(TARGETS)` command flow accepts only targets **created within the same directory**.

So you need either move the `add_library()` call into the top-level directory, or split `install(TARGETS)` call into per-target ones, and move each of them into the corresponding subdirectory.

Since CMake 3.13 `install(TARGETS)` [can work](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/command/install.html#targets) even with targets created in other directories.

> `install(TARGETS)` can install targets that were created in other directories. When using such cross-directory install rules, running `make install` (or similar) from a subdirectory will not guarantee that targets from other directories are up-to-date.

Comment: This is solved in 3.13: install: [Allow installing targets created in another directory](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/merge_requests/2152)

Comment: moving `add_library()`to top level is **not** enough

Comment: @woodz: Could you elaborate, why this is not enough?

Comment: @Tsyvarev: because the top level is not the same dir, if you have multiple subdirs and you wanna pick something from the one and something from the other

Comment: If you have multiple subdirs, which contains libraries you want to install, then before CMake 3.13 you need to move **all** `add_library` calls, corresponding to the installed libraries, into the top-level. I see no specifics of the case with "multiple subdirs" against the case with a single subdir. Of course, moving `add_library` call is not convenient in some cases. But my answer doesn't imply that it will fit for any project.

Answer (score 5):

Even though it would help seeing the `CMakeLists.txt` files contained in the subdirectories, I guess they contain `add_executable` and/or `add_library` statements to create your stuff.
Also, because of your example, I guess you are using the same name of your directories for your targets.
That said, you should know that symbols defined in a `CMakeLists.txt` file in a subdirectory are not visible by default within the context of the `CMakeLists.txt` file in the parent directory. Because of that, you should rather move your `install` statements within the `CMakeLists.txt` files within your subdirectories.
This should solve the problem, if my thoughts were right. Otherwise, I strongly suggest you to post in your question also the content of the other files above mentioned.

Anyway, the error is quite clear.
The file that contains the `install` statement for the target named `X` does not contain a target creation statement (`add_executable` and the others) that gives birth to that target, so it goes on saying that that target does not exist in that directory.

Answer (score 5):

This still seems to be a pain point in CMake 3.11.

In our codebase, we have many targets defined in subdirectories and need to create an assortment of installers with different configurations and (potentially overlapping) combinations of targets.

Here's my solution:

- Before calling `add_subdirectory` in your root CMakeLists.txt file, create a `GLOBAL` property with the names of the target(s) you want to include in your installer.
- Wrap target creation functions (`add_executable`, etc.) in your own custom functions. Within those functions check if the target is present in the global property, and invoke `install` accordingly.

That approach allows you to centralize installer configuration.

Also: To support creation of multiple installers, we populate our global list along with other installer properties in separate .cmake files. When we invoke `cmake`, we pass the name of the installer configuration CMake file as a command-line argument. Our root CMakeLists.txt file simply calls `include` with that file.

Comment: This sounds interesting... but without samples of what you're talking about... I just can't follow it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do like this:

```
add_subdirectory(execA)
add_subdirectory(libB)

function(install_all_targets DIR)
    get_property(TGTS DIRECTORY "${DIR}" PROPERTY BUILDSYSTEM_TARGETS)
    foreach(TGT IN LISTS TGTS)
        message(STATUS "Target: ${TGT}")
        install(TARGETS ${TGT}
                RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
                LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
                ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib)
    endforeach()

    get_property(SUBDIRS DIRECTORY "${DIR}" PROPERTY SUBDIRECTORIES)
    foreach(SUBDIR IN LISTS SUBDIRS)
    install_all_targets("${SUBDIR}")
    endforeach()
endfunction()

install_all_targets(.)
```