# cmake not moving targets to install directory

Tags: cmake

My project is structured as follows

```
ProjDir
| - CMakeLists.txt
| - SubDir1
| | - CMakeLists.txt
| | - src
| | - inc
| - SubDir2
| | - CMakeLists.txt
| | - src
| | - inc
```

I have targets in each subdirectory and the subdirectories are included in the main `CMakeLists.txt` as follows.

```
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/SubDir1)
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/SubDir2)
```

My targets in each subdirectory are installed with the cmake function `install`. These commands are in the `CMakeLists.txt` of respective subdirectories and are specified per-target (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34444949/4782513) post).

```
install(TARGETS exe1 DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/bin CONFIGURATIONS Release)
```

While I'm able to successfully compile, the `install` command doesn't move the binaries to `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/bin` but rather finishes after generated the output:

```
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: ""
```

How could I resolve this?

Comment: You may omit `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/` from `DESTINATION`. The docs state: "If a relative path is given it is interpreted relative to the value of the CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX variable." As you limited the CONFIGURATIONS for which to install, are you building Release and not Debug? Try to remove that for testing purposes.

Comment: Another thing that comes to mind, where is your project call located? Only the top level directory CMakeLists.txt should contain a project call.

Comment: I was making project calls in every subdirectory. I've now corrected this. Also, I've removed `CONFIGURATIONS`. These two things resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, default build configuration is **empty**: neither debug, nor release, etc. It can be easily found from the CMake output:

```
-- Install configuration: ""
```

Because your `install` command is "tagged" with `Release` configuration, it is not triggered by default (with *empty* configuration).