# Install a target defined in an included directory

Tags: cmake

Given the directory structure:

```
foo
| CMakeLists.txt
+--bar
   | CMakeLists.txt
   | hello_world.cpp
```

If we have the top-level `CMakeLists.txt` looking like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
add_subdirectory(bar)
```

And the subdirectory like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
add_library(BarLibrary STATIC hello_world.cpp)
install(TARGETS BarLibrary ARCHIVE DESTINATION .)
```

This works as expected. However, in our real example, the `bar` subdirectory is supplied by a third-party that knows nothing about installation, so it is just these first two lines:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
add_library(BarLibrary STATIC hello_world.cpp)
```

So, we want our top-level `CMakeLists.txt` to be like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
add_subdirectory(bar)
# Somehow import bar/BarLibrary
install(TARGETS BarLibrary ARCHIVE DESTINATION .)
```

However, the code above produces the error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:4 (install):
  install TARGETS given target "BarLibrary" which does not exist in this
  directory.
```

We know that the target is always called BarLibrary, and we could solve the problem by a bunch of `if()`s to handle STATIC versus DYNAMIC, Windows versus Linux, etc and use `install(FILES`, but is there an easier way to access a target defined in a sub-directory? Note we are limited to CMake 3.51 or earlier.

Comment: Does your `CMakeLists.txt` change work?  I'd expect what you provided at the end of your question to work, and you can handle shared/static libraries by just specifying a `DESTINATION` for each.

Comment: No, it doesn't work; I've updated the question with the error text.

Comment: How does this question differ from [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34443128/cmake-install-targets-in-subdirectories)? If you are looking for modern approach, than it involves updating to CMake 3.13 where given restriction has been vanished.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Yup, that's the identical problem! Thanks for the link, and that confirms my suspicions. I've marked this as a duplicate.