# Build installer from target located in submodule

Tags: windows, cmake, nsis, cpack

My project structure is like this

```
project
|-submodule1
|-submodule2
...
CMakeList.txt
```

Every submodule has CMakeList and my executable is build in submodule1:

```
add_executable(submodule1 ${SOURCES} ${MOC_HEADERS} ${RSRCS})
```

Now it get's tricky for me. I want to build an installer with Cpack and have already configured everything in my project's CMake file which basically consists of add_subdirectory(submodule1), add_subdirectory(submodule2), ...
**How do I implement this?**

In an example project with no submodules I just called

```
add_executable("${PROJECT_NAME}" helloworld.cpp)
install(TARGETS "${PROJECT_NAME}" DESTINATION bin)
install(FILES "helloworld.cpp" DESTINATION src)
<Cpack stuff>
```

but this does not work here because the exe is build in submodule. I also have no clue what to google for.

Comment: Can you simply move the `install()` and CPack commands into the submodule where your `add_executable()` call is?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CMake install (TARGETS in subdirectories)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34443128/cmake-install-targets-in-subdirectories)

Comment: I've seen this topic and use cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1), but it does not work like this:
    install(TARGETS simApp
            RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
            LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
            ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib)
I do not get an error, but I see repeating messages of
Running C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe C:/Users/User04/Documents/Projekte/concept_simulation "-GCodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles" "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release" "-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:STRING=C:/Qt/Tools/mingw730_64/bin/g++.exe" ...

Comment: Adding the CPack commands to the submodule does not work, the installer is not build and there's no error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the command:

```
install(TARGETS "${PROJECT_NAME}")
```

and running `make package` from the build directory was enough.